# Get traceId from ValidationProblem in ASPNet Core 3.1 Api Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am using Refit on my Xamarin client app.
When I call my Api and there are ModelState/Validation errors I return a `ValidationProblem(ModelState)` to my client. Refit then throws a `ValidationApiException`. In the exception there is a traceId.

How can I get the `traceId` on the server side so I can log it?
I would like to be able to correlate client device logs with the server when there are bugs/problems.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [source](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/Infrastructure/DefaultProblemDetailsFactory.cs#L90) shows that the `traceId` property is retrieved like this:

> ```
> var traceId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? httpContext?.TraceIdentifier;
> ```

If you want to get hold of this inside a controller, you can use this like so:

```
public IActionResult MyAction()
{
    // using System.Diagnostics for Activity
    var traceId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext?.TraceIdentifier;

    // ...
}
```

Note that `httpContext` changed to `HttpContext`, which is a property of `ControllerBase`. If you want to access this outside of a controller, you might need to use `IHttpContextAccessor` instead.